# one to one correspondence of Ideals in a ring and its localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $S$ a mutiplicatively closed subset. In my text book, it is stated that:

> there is one to one correspondence of  *prime* ideals in ring $A$ (not meeting $S$) and *prime* ideals in its localization $S^{-1}A$.

And my question is if we can remove the word *prime* and state an 1-1 relation to any ideal?

Comment: Which book? I would expect any book to mentioning this to have a discussion about which ideals are extended/contracted. Come to think of it, I don't remember Lang doing this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the ideals $(x)$ and $(xy)$ in the ring $k[x,y]$ and its localization $k[x,y]_{(x)}$.

Comment: can you give more detail about it? I'm not quite familiar with that

Comment: @annimal There are two things you should be concerned about: why $(x) \neq (xy)$ in $k[x,y]$ and why $(x) = (xy)$ in $k[x,y]_{(x)}$. Which of these would you like more clarification on?