# When is there a bijection between the ideals of $A$ and the ideals of $S^{-1}A$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

I know that there's a bijection between the *prime* ideals of $S^{-1}A$ and the *prime* ideals of $A$ not meeting $S$ -- some people (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066410/one-to-one-correspondence-of-ideals-in-a-ring-and-its-localization?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309957/correspondence-between-the-ideals-of-a-ring-r-and-its-localization-at-a-submonoi)) have asked about whether this is true for *all* ideals. I see that this isn't true in general, but I'm wondering what conditions have to be met for it to be true.

Generally, I know that every ideal in $S^{-1}A$ is an extension of an ideal of $A$, but this "correspondence" is not injective. So maybe one way I could approach this problem is figuring out when two ideals have the same extension. On the flip side, knowing that every ideal of $S^{-1}A$ is equal to the extension of its contraction, maybe I could also try figuring out why the contraction of $I \subset S^{-1}A$ is "special" among the ideals of $A$ that extend to it.

Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulty with either of these approaches. Could someone possibly finish a classification of when this happens (maybe using some other idea)? One possible example is the obvious isomorphism when $S = \{1\}$; is this the *only* example?

Comment: Your last example is far from the only one; this happens more generally if $S$ contains only units from $A$.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but then the same isomorphism results. Maybe I'm looking for an example where the map $A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ isn't an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a nonzero commutative ring and $S\subset A$ a multiplicatively closed subset. If $s\in S$ is not invertible in $A$ then the ideal $(s)$ generated by $s$ is contained in a maximal ideal, so $(s)\neq A$. The canonical map
$$A\ \longrightarrow\ S^{-1}A,$$
maps the principal ideal $(s)\subset A$ to the unit ideal $(1)\subset S^{-1}A$, and so this map does not induce a bijection between the ideals of the two rings.

On the other hand, if $S$ contains only units, then the canonical map is an isomorphism.